# How to use filter array to remove items in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
    var arr = [1,2,4,5,1,2,3,4,5];
```

And I have another array:

```
    var removeArr = [1,3,5];
```

I want it to remove elements in **arr** that has in the **removeArr**:

```
    var result = arr.filter(function(item){
                 return item != removeArr[???];
                 });
```

I have tried to iterate it using loop but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check if the other array contains the item

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: How do I choose the best answer if all answer are the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can reach the desired output using `Array#filter` aswell as `Array#indexOf` functions.

```js
var arr = [1,2,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
    removeArr = [1,3,5],
    result = arr.filter(function(item){
      return removeArr.indexOf(item) == -1;
    });
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var arr = [1,2,4,5,1,2,3,4,5];
 
 var removeArr = [1,3,5];
 
 var result = arr.filter(x => !removeArr.includes(x));
 
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and test against while filtering.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    removeArray = [1, 3, 5],
    result = array.filter((s => a => !s.has(a))(new Set(removeArray)));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a clever one! Took some time to understand how it works, thanks for it.

Comment: it uses a closure over a set.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out after rewriting into regular IIFE template.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = arr.filter(function(item){
    return removeArr.indexOf(item) === -1; // if the item is not included in removeArr, then return true (include it in the result array)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a value is in an array by checking if the index of the item is not -1.

`var result = arr.filter(item => removeArr.indexOf(item) === -1)`